# Passing result of find to custom functions

Tags: bash, find, exec

I write a bash script:

```
   #!/bin/bash
    function test_echo
    {
        echo $0
        echo $1
        echo $2
        echo $#
    }
    test_echo
```

I try:

```
find test.sh -type f -exec test_echo '{}' \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec `./test.sh {}` \;
```

but it doesn't work.

I need a way to scan file from a folder (I use find) and for each file call a function ( foo_fonction() ) with in parameter the full path of the file.

```
 find . -type f -exec foo_fonction '{}' \;
```

And how to have the parameter (full path) in the foo_fonction() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to go about this:

1: You can put either put the function definition as part of your find files script:

(Let's call this `find_stuff.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

test_echo() {
    echo $0
    echo $1
    echo $2
    echo $#
}

files=$(find $(pwd) -type f)
for f in $files
do
    test_echo "$f"
done
```

Explanation of what this does:

- A new shell is spawned to run this script if you do `./find_stuff.sh`
- First it defines the `test_echo()` function,
- Then it finds all of the files under the current working directory recursively
- Note that since we specified `$(pwd)` as the search directory, which will be an absolute path, the results returned by `find` will be absolute paths too - as you desired.
- Then for each of these files, pass its file path to the `test_echo` function

2: Put the function definition elsewhere, but you still want a `find_stuff.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find $(pwd) -type f)
for f in $files
do
    ./test.sh "$f"
done
```

and `test.sh` should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_echo () {
    echo $0
    echo $1
    echo $2
    echo $#
}

test_echo $@
```

Note the last line `test_echo $@` - the `$@` part is what you were missing before.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. What's $@ do?

Comment: @user1778354 That is correct =) It's defensive programming practice to pass all the variables in (more information) so if in the future you run into problems, it's easier to debug.

Comment: Your solution is guaranteed to fail for files with spaces in them.

Comment: I have fixed pattern of filenames (tar files generated in a directory). This helped me a lot in that case. Thank you.

mydir contains `filename-date.tar.gz` file which I had to search and untar in loop.

Answer (score 2):

Find cannot execute internal commands.

It can execute just commands found on the disk.

The explanation is simple: When the process `find` starts, it cannot see in the environments of the process that started it (forked by `bash` in this case) the internal commands.

The process `bash` passes in the environment of find the $PATH, but does not pass it's internals.

You need to add the function into a `file.sh`, make this one executable, add the path to the script in $PATH [like "." if the `pwd` of `bash` is the same as the place of `file.sh`], and execute it in these conditions.